# Truncating string on jquery chart with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

So I searched for possible solutions to this problem however the ones posted around google dont work( e.g. overflow, text-overflow, z-index) I attached the image below. My issue is that strings go past the chart border is there a CSS property i could be missing? thanks appreciate the help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAyvu.png

Comment: Put `overflow: hidden;` on the ***chart container element***.

Comment: please post your code